# Magento2 Override Block - Invalid template file problem

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, overrides, catalog

I would like to Override `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description`, but I've got:

> [2017-08-21 16:03:47] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file:
>   'product/view/attribute.phtml' in module: 'Test_Catalog' block's name:
>   'product.info.sku' [] []

and `detail.phtml` is missing on frontend on product page.

I have done:

`etc/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" type="Test\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" />
</config>
```

in `Test/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Description`:

```
<?php
namespace Test\Catalog\Block\Product\View;

class Description extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
{

    /**
     * @return array|bool
     */
    public function getConfigProductChild()
    {
         //function returns child products in array
    }
}
```

I'm using **TemplateMonster** Theme so I would like to use `getConfigProductChild` function in :

```
project/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/framework/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml
```

I read that I should type referenceBlock with template and Mine block but it doest works (or I did something wrong?).
Tried something like that:

in view/frontend/layout/default.xml of mine module:

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details" class="Test\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Instead of `Magento_Catalog` I tried also use TemplateMonser etc.

Do You know what's the problem?

EDIT:

path for missing pthml:

```
project/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/framework/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml
```

layout using details.phtml:
`project/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/framework/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current theme, you need to make change in `catalog_product_view.xml` file as below.

If your new template still exist in `Magento_Catalog` module then update code like below:

```
<block class="Test\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media" remove ="true"/>
```

If your new template still exist in `Test_Catalog` module then update code like below:

```
<block class="Test\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="Test_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media" remove ="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer and your time! template exist in: `/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/framework/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml`. In this case I should use `Magento_Catalog`, right? It doesnt works.

Comment: `Magento_Catalog` yes it is correct. Can you please share how you are using in layout and pls check log also

Comment: I just edit my post

Comment: `framework` is the only theme in TemplateMonster package ?
Also in your updated layout code - you have not change path `Magento_Catal‌​og:: ` this one is missing

Comment: Yes, I had to add `Magento_Catal‌​og::` to TemplateMonster layout also. Thanks!